# list the pods zone wise

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, awk

I am trying to list the pod's zone wise,

for this, I am fetching the details of the node, where it has zones details along with Node Identifier, and whereas pods list has common Node Identifier, Now I want to club both results and want to print the pod's zone wise.
`kubectl get nodes --label-columns failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone | awk '{print $1,$6}' | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' | column -t > Nodes`

`kubectl get pods -n app -o wide | awk '{print $1, $7}' | column -t | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' > pods`

The desired output should be like

```
zone 1a
       pod 1   nodename status region
       pod 2   nodename status region

zone 1b
       pod 1   nodename status region
       pod 2   nodename status region
zone 1c
       pod 1   nodename status region
       pod 2   nodename status region
zone 2a
       pod 1   nodename status region
       pod 2   nodename status region
```

script i tried,

```
# bash scrip to print pods in each zone


kubectl get nodes --label-columns failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone | awk '{print $1,$6}' | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' | column -t > A
# get the pods list from app namespace
kubectl get pods -n app -o wide | awk '{print $1, $7}' | column -t | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' > B
# Compare file A and B and list the pods in each zone
# > AB
cat A B 

cat B | while read LINE;do
  matching_col=$(echo "$LINE"| awk '{print $2}');
  append_col=$(echo "$LINE"| awk '{print $1}');
  cat A | grep  $matching_col | head -1
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   line1="`cat A | grep $matching_col | head -1`    ${append_col}"
   echo $line1 >> AB
  fi
done
# write the available zones list to C
cat AB | awk '{print $3,$6}' | column -t | sort > C
# compare A and B and list the pods in each zone, comparing C and A
for i in `cat C | awk '{print $1}'`; do
  echo "pods in zone:" $i
  kubectl get pods -n app -o wide | sed -n "/$i/p" 
done

# delete the files
# rm AB
# rm A
# rm B
# rm C
```

output from Node > A

```
ip-192-5-1-199.eu-west-2.compute.internal  eu-west-2a
ip-192-5-1-216.eu-west-2.compute.internal  eu-west-2a
ip-192-5-2-212.eu-west-2.compute.internal  eu-west-2b
ip-192-5-2-36.eu-west-2.compute.internal   eu-west-2b
ip-192-5-3-157.eu-west-2.compute.internal
ip-192-5-3-222.eu-west-2.compute.internal  eu-west-2c
ip-192-5-3-45.eu-west-2.compute.internal   eu-west-2c
```

output from pods > B

```
app-node-setup              ip-192-5-3-157.eu-west-2.compute.internal
app-node-setup              ip-192-5-2-212.eu-west-2.compute.internal
app-node-setup              ip-192-5-1-216.eu-west-2.compute.internal
app-node-setup              ip-192-5-2-36.eu-west-2.compute.internal
app-node-setup              ip-192-5-3-45.eu-west-2.compute.internal
app-node-setup               ip-192-5-3-222.eu-west-2.compute.internal
app-node-setup              ip-192-5-1-199.eu-west-2.compute.internal
app-operator-5                     ip-192-5-3-45.eu-west-2.compute.internal
telnet-1-accesspool         ip-192-5-1-199.eu-west-2.compute.internal
telnet-1-accesspool          ip-192-5-3-222.eu-west-2.compute.internal
telnet-1-manager            ip-192-5-2-212.eu-west-2.compute.internal
storage-set-from-configmap-1-ss-5  ip-192-5-2-36.eu-west-2.compute.internal
storage-set-from-configmap-1-ss-1  ip-192-5-3-157.eu-west-2.compute.internal
storage-set-from-configmap-1-ss-2  <none>
```

`Actual Output`

```
kubectl get nodes --label-columns failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone

NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION            ZONE
ip-192-0-1-199.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    master,worker   23d   v1.20.11+e880017   eu-west-2a
ip-192-0-1-216.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    master,worker   23d   v1.20.11+e880017   eu-west-2a
ip-192-0-2-212.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    master,worker   23d   v1.20.11+e880017   eu-west-2b
ip-192-0-2-36.eu-west-2.compute.internal    Ready    master,worker   23d   v1.20.11+e880017   eu-west-2b
ip-192-0-3-157.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    <none>          20d   v1.20.11+c343126
ip-192-0-3-222.eu-west-2.compute.internal   Ready    master,worker   23d   v1.20.11+e880017   eu-west-2c
ip-192-0-3-40.eu-west-2.compute.internal    Ready    master,worker   23d   v1.20.11+e880017   eu-west-2c

 kubectl get pods -n app -o wide
 NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE                                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
app-node-setup-6qckk                1/1     Running   0          17d   169.24.206.214   ip-192-0-3-157.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
app-node-setup-ccwww                1/1     Running   0          17d   169.24.184.7     ip-192-0-2-212.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
app-node-setup-pn8vs                1/1     Running   0          17d   169.24.1925.242   ip-192-0-1-216.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
app-node-setup-pqm7s                1/1     Running   0          17d   169.24.56.85     ip-192-0-2-36.eu-west-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
app-node-setup-qxd5c                1/1     Running   0          17d   169.24.246.139   ip-192-0-3-40.eu-west-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
app-node-setup-rpm56                1/1     Running   0          17d   169.24.25.2192    ip-192-0-3-222.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
app-node-setup-wbf75                1/1     Running   0          17d   169.24.5.209     ip-192-0-1-199.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
app-operator-0                      1/1     Running   0          17d   169.24.246.137   ip-192-0-3-40.eu-west-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
telnet-1-accesspool-1-ss-0           2/2     Running   3          17d   169.24.5.2192     ip-192-0-1-199.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
telnet-1-accesspool-1-ss-1           2/2     Running   2          17d   169.24.25.212    ip-192-0-3-222.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
telnet-1-manager-1-ss-0              4/4     Running   1          17d   169.24.184.8     ip-192-0-2-212.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
storage-set-from-configmap-1-ss-0   2/2     Running   3          17d   169.24.56.1923    ip-192-0-2-36.eu-west-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
storage-set-from-configmap-1-ss-1   2/2     Running   6          17d   169.24.206.218   ip-192-0-3-157.eu-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
storage-set-from-configmap-1-ss-2   0/2     Pending   0          17d   <none>           <none>                                     <none>           <none>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts and your expected output. What's missing is the **exact** corresponding input.

Comment: I have added the script which I attempted, but still, I am not able to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. But we cannot guess what your inputs are. Please **provide the input corresponding to your expected output**. Most people will not install kubernetes and run these `kubectl` commands to get these inputs you don't show, all this just to answer a text processing question that has very few to do with kubernetes. So, please show us examples of what `kubectl get nodes --label-columns failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone`, `kubectl get pods -n app -o wide` or `kubectl get pods -n app -o wide` produce.

Comment: Hi Renaud, Thank you, i have added the outputs of these commands, if you observe $1 file A and $2 in File B are matching, now i need the logic to print the names (pods $1 in file B) segregated by zone wise ($2 in File A)

Comment: Are `output from...` actually your input files? If so, please don't refer to them as output as that's just confusing. The block you have listed under `The desired output should be like` is just a bunch of placeholder text, what we need to see is the expected output given the sample input you provide. We need something we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: Please copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about as instructed by the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag you used and then let us know if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution not tested, since there is no testing input in the question.

#### script.awk

```
FNR == 1 { #skip first line in each input
  next;
}
FNR == NR { # read input #1: kubectl get nodes --label-columns failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
  nodesArr[$6] = nodesArr[$6] $1; # each nodeArr[] has a list of ip-addr
}
FNR != NR { # read input #2: kubectl get pods -n app -o wide
  ipArr[$7] = ipArr[$7] $1; # each ipArr[] has a list of pod names
}
END {
  for (node in nodesArr) { # for each node
    region = gensub(/[^-]+$/, "\0", 1, node); # extract the region from node
    printf("%s\n", region); # output region
    split(nodesArr[node], tempIpArr); # convert list of ip-addr to array tempIpArr[]
    for (currIp in tempIpArr) { # for each ip in tempIpArr[]
      split(ipArr[currIp], podsArr); # convert list of pods to array podsArr[]
      podsCount = 1; # reset pods count
      for (pod in podsArr) { # for each pod in podsArr[]
        printf("\%s %i %s status region\n", pod, podsCount, currIp); # print the pod it ordinal and currIp
        podsCount++; # advance pods count
      }
    }
    print; # add a new line before next region
  }
}
```

#### running:

```
awk -f script.awk <(kubectl get nodes --label-columns failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone) <(kubectl get pods -n app -o wide)
```

Comment: Hi Ed Morton, I have attached the un modified output of both commands above, With the script provided, in the output i see only last three pods are being printed. Also i see following error.
`awk: script.awk:19: warning: escape sequence `\%' treated as plain `%'`

Comment: Hi DudiBoy, Thanks for a quick response, o/p I'm getting is

```awk: script.awk:19: warning: escape sequence `\%' treated as plain `%'
us-east-
storage-set-from-configmap-1-ss-2   2/2     Running    7  21d   169.24.72.145    canary-wdc-subnet-a-vsi-2   <none>     <none>
us-east-

storage-set-from-configmap-1-ss-2   2/2     Running   7   21d   169.24.72.145    canary-wdc-subnet-a-vsi-2   <none>    <none>
us-east-```
Also it is listing details of last three pods, and last character in zone name is also missing.